# Adding initialized ViewModels to ObservableCollection displaying null property values

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

When adding ViewModels to an ObservableCollection, which is shown on the MainWindow as an ItemsControl with the ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource. The initial values of the View are displayed as null. I know this because on debugging and changing the value of the TextBox I see that the Name field is set to null, but when I press the button to add new ViewModels it is setting the Name field but then not displaying the name. This app has been condensed for ease of debugging. So it seems that while the ObservableCollection is communicating to the view it is not receiving the proper values somehow.

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="LifeCalculator.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:LifeCalculator.Views" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LifeFinanceCalculator.Views"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Margin="47,24,373,269" Content="Add ViewModels" Command="{Binding AddCommandItem}"/>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="28,75,37,72">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListExampleItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:exampleView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using LifeFinanceCalculator.ViewModels;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Prism.Commands;

namespace LifeCalculator.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<exampleViewModel> _listExampleItems;
        public ObservableCollection<exampleViewModel> ListExampleItems 
        {
            get => _listExampleItems;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _listExampleItems, value);
            }
        }
        public ICommand AddCommandItem { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _listExampleItems = new ObservableCollection<exampleViewModel>();
            AddCommandItem = new DelegateCommand(ListItem);
        }

        private void ListItem()
        {
            _listExampleItems.Add(new exampleViewModel() { Name = "Chris" });
            _listExampleItems.Add(new exampleViewModel() { Name = "Olivia" });
        }
    }
}
```

**exampleView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LifeFinanceCalculator.Views.exampleView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**exampleViewModel**

```
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace LifeFinanceCalculator.ViewModels
{
    public class exampleViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _name, value);
            }
        }
        public exampleViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have an idea of what you're getting at, I'm assuming that the Prism ViewModelLocator is probably Re-Initializing the Datacontext... Therefore of course I have null values... Does that sound right?

Comment: Oh Prism!  Yes basically.  It's a case of orphaned VMs due to multiple VMs.  It can happen too with straight-up WPF (say no Prism, no DI) when someone sets the `DataContext` in the XAML and code-behind by mistake.  Been there done that ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewModelLocator` used by *Prism* was the issue. The `ViewModelLocator` re-intializes the View with a new ViewModel. To solve the issue :

`prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel = "False"`

Comment: Actually, for Prism 8, you have to do that in nearly all your view models, because AutoWire=True is the new default.